# check permission showing none

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

i have added user X in sharepoint group A and group A having Full Control now when I am using check permissions for user X,result is showing none.

Totally confused,any help?

I am using sharepoint online.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if the user X is in the group A.
2. Remove the user X and re-add the user X into the group A, and check the result.
3. Grant the user with permission level directly in site permission, and check the result.
4. Create a new SharePoint group with full control permission and add the user X to the new group, and check the result.